# Counting how many items in a list are identical

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two lists of the same size, a and b. I want to get a count for how many items in the list have the same number at the same index. I.e if `a = [1,2,3,4]` and `b = [1,4,5,4]` then the returned sum would be 2.

I have tried this :

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    sum = 0
    if a[i] == b[i]:
        sum+=1
```

Comment: Take `sum = 0` out of the loop.

Comment: This is a very common beginner error, I can't understand why they don't see the obvious problem with it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```py
sum(i==j for i,j in zip(a,b))
```

Answer (score 0):

For the minimal fix to your code, you need to move the sum initialization out of the loop:

```
sum = 0
for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i] == b[i]:
        sum+=1
```

But there's a pretty oneliner in the comments also.